Issue with accessing data in 'updateUser' method with Supabase
Firstly, I'd like to say that I am just starting with programming and not sure if the provided details are sufficient.
I'm encountering an error when trying to access data within the updateUser method in Supabase.
Supabase docs - Update user 
  const updateUserMetadata = async (formData) => {
    const idSegmentOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e10).toString()
    const idSegmentTwo = Date.now().toString()
    const id = idSegmentOne + idSegmentTwo
    const snippet = {id: id, name: formData, body: input.input}

    try {   
      const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.updateUser({
        data: { mdSnippets: [ ...data.user.user_metadata.mdSnippets, snippet ] }
      })

      // console.log(data)

      error
        ? toast.error('Saving snippet failed.')
        : toast.success('Snippet saved successfully.')
      console.log('Updating metadata error (try):', error)
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error('Saving snippet failed')
      console.log('Updating metadata error (catch):', error.message)
    }
  }

I believe that the problem is related to spreading the existing values in the array:
[ ...data.user.user_metadata.mdSnippets, snippet ]
When attempting to access the data object to spread those values, I'm getting Cannot access 'data' before initialization error. The error comes from the catch block console log.
The function is called from another component in the following way:
  const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    updateUserMetadata(formData.snippetName)
    // getUserMetadata()
  }

I think that I am trying to access the relevant key-value pair in the correct way as I have checked the shape of the object with the commented out console log you can see after the try block.

I've tried declaring data as empty object before the try block, like below, but I am not even sure if that applies to the scope of the try block (I think it doesn't) since the data in thy block is deconstructed from the Supabase method.
let data = {}

Tried setTimeout to see if maybe after some time the data object would be initialized, but it is not (also tried longer time intervals than 1 second).
try {
  const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.updateUser({
    data: {
      mdSnippets: await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve([...data.user.user_metadata.mdSnippets, snippet])
        }, 1000)
      })
    }
  })

But... everything works as expected if I modify the array to contain only the snippet without spreading existing data.
    try {   
      const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.updateUser({
        data: { mdSnippets: [ snippet ] }
      })

Thanks

I went to Supabase discord, they advised that for this to work, I need to first define the data object using the 'getUser' method and then use this object in the 'upadteUser' method.
Haven't tried it yet, but their suggestion seems to be right on point. I've re-read the docs and I think that this will work. Will try today or during the weekend.

It worked! In order to update user metadata, I had to use both Supabase methods ('getUser' and 'updateUser') like they said on discord. As you can see, in my original solution I attempt to update metadata with 'updateUser' directly, I had to first obtain user data with 'getUser', than I created a variable where I spread existing data obtained there and add the 'snippet'. After that I used the 'updateUser' with that variable.
